# Rails 3 best_in_place Edit Nested Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place, inplace-editing

Given

```
<% @incidents.each_with_index do |incident,i| %>
```

I can't figure out how to in place edit attributes on incident and parent associations such as incident.user or incident.contact

This works for example:

```
best_in_place incident, :notes, type: :input,  nil: 'Add Note'
```

But I can't figure out how to do incident.customer  to get a drop down of Customer.all (incident belongs_to :customer)

I get various errors each way I try it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, in your controller's show action, or wherever's relevant:

```
@customer = Customer.all.map { |c| [c.id, c.customer_name] } # or whatever the customer name attribute is
```

In your view:

```
= best_in_place incident, :notes,  :type => :select, :collection => @customer
```

This produces the [[a,b], [c,d]] format that the [docs](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#select) say is needed.

It would be less wordy with Customer.pluck(:id, :name) but that's only in Edge Rails at the time of writing ([link to guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck)).